# How to create security group in aws cdk in python?

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group, aws-cdk

Hi I am trying to write seurity group using aws cdk. I know how to write it in using cloud formation.
Below is my cloud formation template.

```
MerchWebServicesSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
      GroupDescription: "EC2 Services Security Group"
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: "infra-vpc-base::VpcId"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "80"
          ToPort: "80"
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref MerchWebServicesLoadBalancerSecurityGroup
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "443"
          ToPort: "443"
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref MerchWebServicesLoadBalancerSecurityGroup
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 31000
          ToPort: 65535
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref MerchWebServicesLoadBalancerSecurityGroup
```

I tried to write security group as below in python cdk.

```
  mws_vpc_sg  = ec2.SecurityGroup(stack, "MerchWebServicesSecurityGroup",
        description= "Allow ssh access to ec2 instances",
        security_group_name= "MerchWebServicesSecurityGroup",
        vpc= vpc
    );

 mws_vpc_sg.add_ingress_rule(?, Port.tcp(80));
```

Above I want to add sourceSecurityGroupId and port. Can someone help me to write this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the other security group in CDK as well, you can just pass the security group as peer.

```
mws_vpc_sg.add_ingress_rule(load_balancer_sg, Port.tcp(80));
```

If you have created the security group somewhere else you need to obtain a ISecurityGroup from it using the static method:

```
var load_balancer_sg = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, 'loadbalancer_sg', THE_ID_OF_THE_SG)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not able to access from aws_cdk import (aws_ec2 as ec2). I can access s3,sqs and all but not ecs and ec2. May I know the reason? I get error ImportError: cannot import name 'aws_ecs' from 'aws_cdk' (unknown location)

Comment: have you installed the aws_ec2 dependency using `pip i aws-cdk.aws-ec2`?. You probably should edit your question if you cannot use ec2. You are using it in your example as well.